# Wrong graph in Dagger 2 with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am trying to use Dagger 2 with Kotlin and I am missing something. The problem comes when I try to inject an MVP presenter into the `Fragment`.

These are my files:

**AppClass**

```
class AppClass : Application(), HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
            .inject(this)
    }

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> = dispatchingAndroidInjector

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: AppClass private set
    }
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
                    AppModule::class,
                    ActivityBuilder::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(appClass: AppClass)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(appClass: AppClass): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

**AppModule**

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(app : AppClass) = app

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabaseManager() = DatabaseManager()
}
```

**ActivityBuilder**

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ActivityModule::class, HomeFragmentProvider::class])
    internal abstract fun bindHomeActivity(): HomeActivity
}
```

**HomeFragmentProvider**

```
@Module
public abstract class HomeFragmentProvider {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = HomeFragmentModule.class)
    abstract HomeFragment provideHomeFragmentFactory();
}
```

**HomeFragmentModule**

```
@Module
class HomeFragmentModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideHomePresenter(databaseManager: DatabaseManager): HomeContract.Presenter {
        return HomePresenter(databaseManager)
    }
}
```

**HomeFragment**

```
class HomeFragment : HomeContract.View {

    @Inject lateinit var mPresenter: HomeContract.Presenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (arguments != null) {
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        return view
    }

    companion object {

        private val STARTING_PAGE_INDEX = 0

        fun newInstance(): HomeFragment {
            val fragment = HomeFragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

**Log**

```
...app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/.../di/component/FragmentComponent.java:9: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] ....HomeContract.Presenter cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

I try to inject the `DatabaseManager` in the Activity and works fine so I suppose that my problem is related to the `Fragment` dependencies.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**
**HomePresenter**

```
class HomePresenter() :
BasePresenter<HomeContract.View>(), HomeContract.Presenter {

private lateinit var mDatabaseManager : DatabaseManager

@Inject constructor(databaseManager: DatabaseManager) : this() {
    this.mDatabaseManager = databaseManager
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the problem. If I change the injection in the HomeFragment from `@Inject lateinit var mPresenter: HomeContract.Presenter` to `@Inject lateinit var mPresenter: HomePresenter` everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Define HomePresenter variable as a function parameter, as below:

```
@Module
class HomeFragmentModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideHomePresenter(homePresenter: HomePresenter): HomeContract.Presenter {
            return homePresenter
    }
}
```

Modify your `HomePresenter` class as below:

```
class HomePresenter @Inject constructor(val databaseManager: DatabaseManager) :
BasePresenter<HomeContract.View>(), HomeContract.Presenter {
   ....
}
```

Also, you can use `DatabaseManager` instance from the constructor directly by marking it as `val`, there is no need to define it separately.

In `AppComponent`, try using `AndroidInjectionModule::class` if you are not using support Fragments.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class,
                    AppModule::class,
                    ActivityBuilder::class])
    interface AppComponent {
        ....
    }
```

Hope this will resolve your issue!

Comment: That's not working. The error is the same. Could you post the full code for the presenter?

Comment: Have updated the answer, hope this time it works for you. Though, you can also refer https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvp-architecture/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/mindorks/framework/mvp, for a more generic MVP structure.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I found the solution.